# Why is RemoteMessage.getData() returning null in firebase notifications?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm using the notification composer in firebase to send the following key value pair using **Custom data**:

```
 type : 555
```

I'm not putting double-quotes `""` around `type` and `555` in the notification composer. So in the place for **key** I'm writing `type` and in the place for **value** I'm writing `555` . 
Following is my code to retrieve this value of type :

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


        final Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        final String type = data.get("type");
        Log.e("TAG","Type= "+type);

}
```

But the log output I'm getting is:

```
Type= null
```

Why am I getting null? How do I correctly retrieve the value of the given key?

**EDIT**
It appears that

```
final Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
```

works all right. I put a `Log.e()` statement after this line and it correctly prints 555.  So it appears that `data.get("type")` is returning null even though the key "type" is present. Why is this happening?

Comment: Could you try `final String type = data.get("type").toString();`?

Comment: How was it Nirvan? Did it work?

Comment: @AL. Nope. Like I mentioned in my edit, `data.get("type")` returns null- so doing `toString()` on it just throws a nullPointerException

Comment: @Al But I did fix it in the end. I had defined "type" in strings.xml and had written something like`data.get(R.string.myType)` where `myType` was "type" in strings.xml . Apparently this doesn't work, so I just wrote "type" directly. Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: Strange. I'll try it out on my end if I have some free time tomorrow. In the meantime, could you try sending the payload [via Postman or cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase-cloud-messaging/8242/firebase-cloud-messaging#t=201706061144240182246) and see if it's still the same?

Comment: Tried it out. I also copy-pasted your code. Both works fine for me. Could you post the exact logs for your `Log.e(TAG, data)`?

Comment: I am facing same issue. Have you got working code? Can anyone help us on same?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem. After some search, I came up with the solution below.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    
    RemoteMessage.Notification data = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    String title = data.getTitle();
    String body = data.getBody();
    
    if (data != null){
        // do some work
    }
    
}
```

I tried and it worked for me. I hope it will help others.